# returns empty() values

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity, account, developer

I'm trying to retrieve the contact's account opportunities 
    i gathered all opportunities but when i'm trying to retrieve all opportunities it printing empty.

this is method

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Opportunity> getAccountOpportunities(){

   List<String> oppss = new List<String>();
   Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
   List<Contact> conts = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'test@gmail.com'];
   for(Contact c : conts){

      accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
   }

   List<Account>  accounts = [select name,(select Name from opportunities) from Account where id = :accountIds];   
    for(Account a : accounts){
        for(Opportunity c : a.opportunities){
            String oppname = c.name;
            oppss.add(oppname);
            System.debug(oppname);//printing the opportunities success          
        }

    }

    System.debug(oppss);//successfully getting all opps
    List<Opportunity>  opps = [select name from Opportunity where id = :oppss ];
    System.debug('All Opportunities'+opps);
    //returns empty shows All Opportunities()
    return opps;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in below code

```
List<String> oppss = new List<String>();
for(Account a : accounts){
        for(Opportunity c : a.opportunities){
            String oppname = c.name;
            oppss.add(oppname);
            System.debug(oppname);//printing the opportunities success          
}
```

You are comparing **oppss** list of name with id in SOQL

> List  opps = [select name from Opportunity where id = :oppss ];

**Either you have to compare with list of name or list of opportunity id.**

solution 1:

Change to list id instead list of names .

```
 set<id> oppss = new set<id>();
    for(Account a : accounts)
            for(Opportunity c : a.opportunities)
                oppss.add(c.id);
```

**or**

solution 2 :

Change in SOQL where **id** to **Name**

```
 List<Opportunity>  opps = [select name from Opportunity where name= :oppss ];
```

I Prefer go for solution 1 instead of solution 2, Solution 2 you may be result to get other opportunity because the name conflict also.

**updated:**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Opportunity> getAccountOpportunities(){
       set<id> oppss = new set<id>();
       Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
       List<Contact> conts = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'nithesh_k@persistent.com'];
       for(Contact c : conts)
          accountIds.add(c.AccountId);

        List<Account>  accounts = [select name,(select Name from opportunities) from Account where id = :accountIds];   

        for(Account a : accounts)
            for(Opportunity c : a.opportunities)
                oppss.add(c.id);    

           System.debug('oppss' + oppss);//successfully getting all opps

           List<Opportunity>  opps = [select name from Opportunity where id = :oppss ];
           System.debug('All Opportunities'+opps);
return opps;
}
```

Question 2 :

```
set<id> setOpp =new set<id>();
    for(opportunity o: [select accountID from opportunity ] )
        setOpp.add(o.accountid);

    List<Account>  accounts = [select name,(select Name from opportunities) from Account where id = :accountIds and id= :setOpp];
```